# Bind Border.BackgroundProperty in C#, update issue

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I want to bind the Border.BackgroundProperty in C#. The binding works but the Border-Element is not updating on change.

**UIElement (fb_CoonetionIndicator = Border):**

```
            var indicatorElement = new InputElement("");
        indicatorElement.InputElementType = InputElementTypeEnum.Indicator;
        // verified label binding
        Binding indicatorBinding = new Binding("VerificationText");
        indicatorBinding.Source = ApplicationPersistantDataModel.Instance;
        indicatorElement.local_indicatorlabel.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, indicatorBinding);
        // backgroundcolor binding
        Binding colorBinding = new Binding("VerificationColor");
        colorBinding.Source = ApplicationDynamicDataModel.Instance;
        colorBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        fb_ConnectionIndicator.fb_backGroundBorder.SetBinding(Border.BackgroundProperty, colorBinding);
        fb_ConnectionIndicator.AddElementToStackPanel(indicatorElement);
```

**DataSource:**

```
 public sealed class ApplicationDynamicDataModel
{
    private static ApplicationDynamicDataModel instance = new ApplicationDynamicDataModel();
    public static ApplicationDynamicDataModel Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
        set { instance = value; }
    }

    // verification indicator color
    private SolidColorBrush _verificationColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.GreenYellow);
    public SolidColorBrush VerificationColor
    {
        get { return _verificationColor; }
        set
        {
            _verificationColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VerificationColor");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Class declaration should have *:INotifyPropertyChanged* to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public sealed class ApplicationDynamicDataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

If you do not have it in the declaration, the binding cannot subscribe to the OnPropertyChanged event.